# What is $\partial_1$ of the inhomogeneous bar resolution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I'm working with the inhomogeneous bar resolution, defined as $\cdots \to L_n \overset{\partial_n}\to L_{n-1} \to \cdots \to L_0 \overset{\varepsilon} \to R \to 0$ where $L_i$ is the free $RG$-module over $i$ copies of $G$, and in particular $L_0$ is a free module over the empty symbol $()$. Here, 
$$\partial_n ((x_1 , \ldots, x_n)) = x_1 (x_2 , \ldots, x_n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^i (x_1 , \ldots, x_i x_{i+1} , \ldots, x_n) + (-1)^n (x_1 , \ldots, x_{n-1})$$

and $\varepsilon(1()) = 1$. I'm trying to show that the collection of maps $\gamma_n(x_0 (x_1 , \ldots, x_n) = (x_0 , x_1 , \ldots, x_n), \gamma_{-1}(x) = x()$ is a contracting homotopy, and I'm mostly done, except for the case $\partial_1 \gamma_0 + \gamma_{-1} \varepsilon = id$. My problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to interpret $\partial_1$ by the definition above. It seems like it should be $\partial_1 ((x_1)) = x_1 () + (-1)^1 ()$ since $n-1 = 0$ makes the sum in the middle disappear, but using this interpretation with the contracting map $\gamma_0(x_0 ()) = (x_0)$ doesn't work. The interpretation that it should just be $\partial_1((x_1)) = x_1()$ also doesn't seem to work, however. Should I be interpreting the sum in the middle for the $n=1$ case some other way, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: I changed $$... \to L_n \to^{\partial_n} L_{n-1} \to ... \to L_0 \to^\epsilon R \to 0$$ to $$\cdots \to L_n \overset{\partial_n}\to L_{n-1} \to \cdots \to L_0 \overset{\varepsilon} \to R \to 0.$$ Note that $\to\cdots\to$ looks different from $\to \ldots \to$ and also from $\to\text{...}\to,$ and that last is what you'll see in actual LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is used here) if you code this as \to...\to rather than using \dots or \ldots or \cdots. Also $\overset{\partial_n}\to$ looks different from $\to^{\partial_n}$. If you just google "latex manual" or$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$"latex symbols" you can find things like this. $\qquad$

Comment: I'll be honest and confess I was just being lazy and typing in things I thought would be understood without being as pretty as they could be if I could remember the right way to make something go directly on top of the arrows or summation symbol, or the curvier epsilon symbol, knowing full well someone else was probably going to fix it if I did that. Thank you for the fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first interpretation is correct: $\partial_1((x_1))=x_1()-()$.  I think you may be misinterpreting the definition of $\varepsilon$: note that $\varepsilon$ is supposed to be a map of $RG$-modules, so $$\varepsilon(x())=x\cdot\varepsilon(())=x\cdot 1=1$$ for any $x\in G$, since $G$ acts trivially on $R$.  We thus have
$$\partial_1\gamma_0(x_0())+\gamma_{-1}\varepsilon(x_0())=\partial_1((x_0))+\gamma_{-1}(1)=x_0()-()+()=x_0()$$ for any $x_0\in G$, and so $\partial_1\gamma_0+\gamma_{-1}\varepsilon$ is the identity since it is $R$-linear.